# How to supply one or more servo motors from a PC power supply?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power-electronics, servo, component-selection

I have a PC power suply 800w. The 12V output has max 20A. How can I convert the 12V to 6V and 10A (when 5 servos will work in the same time)?

Comment: Are you sure you have to? Servo itself is a kind of voltage regulator- it drives motor by applying certain voltage. You should only adjust the current gain. Please, post the servo datasheet.

Comment: You need a step down regulator. Or use the 5V rail.

Comment: Right! Let's build 10A stepdown regulator. Or is it easier to just buy the right PS?

Comment: Godolomn, personally i like developing power supplies, but it will consume more time and money than just a right power supply. On the other hand, you probably don't need anything but the PS you have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- I propose to use 5V output which can supply more current with no problems.
2- If not you have to use a DC to DC converter form 12V to 6V. Its efficiency is about 80%, Then you can get up to 12V * 20A * 0.8 / 6V = 32A.
3- Use a power adapter from 220Vac to 6Vdc x 10A.
4- In other hand, IF you connect a lamb of 100 Watt to city power source (220V AC) then current is 100W/220V = 0.45A, now if you connect a heater of 2200 Watt, the current well by 2200W / 220V = 10A. ==> the current depend on the loud power, and the power supply have a maximum current limit

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear : making a DC/DC is almost the worst option. Finding one off the shelf is acceptable, but the it's easier to just buy AC/DC lab supply.